# Wrong line numbers reported when using multiline search

Tags: regex, grep, multiline, ripgrep

Given the following text:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  app_env(:plans, :myapp, [:billing, :plans],
    binding_order: [:config],
    required: true,
    type: :any
  )

  app_env(
    :plans_with_min_amount_of_integrations,
    :myapp,
    [:billing, :plans_with_min_amount_of_integrations],
    binding_order: [:config],
    required: true,
    type: :any
  )
end
```

I'm trying to match with the following condition in mind:

- `myapp` string,
- that is known to be located between `app_env` and `:billing` strings.

To do this, I'm running:

```
rg --replace '$1' --multiline --multiline-dotall "app_env.*?(myapp).*?billing" test.txt
```

I expect the following output

```
2:myapp
10:myapp
```

But for some reason, I'm getting the following output:

```
2:myapp
8:myapp
```

Why? How do I change the regexp to return the correct lines, while retaining the conditions?

Note, that this example is simplified, and is a part of a larger code search effort of precisely looking & replacing the code, so simply running `rg myapp` won't cut it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Author kindly responded to issue in `ripgrep` bug tracker about this: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/2420

It's not an issue with ripgrep, but rather my own faulty expectations based on misunderstanding how line numbers in conjunction with capture groups are calculated.

In a nutshell, a line number always corresponds to the first line of matched string, and not to the first capture group (which I wrongly assumed was the case).

Kudoes goes to [@burntsushi5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619216/burntsushi5)!